# sony camera remote api setCurrentTime call sometimes results in http response 500

Tags: camera, sony, sony-camera-api

I'm using the sample app included with some additions. Sometimes, the call to the setCurrentTime API results in an IOException in the SimpleHttpClient because of an error 500, at other times, it works just fine a minute later with exactly the same code. What could cause this?

Here's a log excerpt from when it's not working:

```
09-26 13:12:42.023 5782-14444/de.sebastian_brocks.camerasony D/SimpleRemoteApi: Response: {"result":["Smart Remote Control SR\/3.01 __MNG__","2.1.2"],"id":6}
09-26 13:12:42.025 5782-14444/de.sebastian_brocks.camerasony D/CameraServiceSony: setting current time
09-26 13:12:42.042 5782-14444/de.sebastian_brocks.camerasony D/SimpleRemoteApi: Request:  {"id":7,"method":"setCurrentTime","version":"1.0","params":[{"dstOffsetMinute":60,"dateTime":"2016-09-26T11:12:42Z","timeZoneOffsetMinute":60}]}
09-26 13:12:42.045 5782-14444/de.sebastian_brocks.camerasony I/System.out: [socket][74] connection /192.168.122.1:8080;LocalPort=59573(10000)
09-26 13:12:42.049 5782-14444/de.sebastian_brocks.camerasony I/System.out: [CDS]connect[/192.168.122.1:8080] tm:10
09-26 13:12:42.052 5782-14444/de.sebastian_brocks.camerasony D/Posix: [Posix_connect Debug]Process de.sebastian_brocks.camerasony :8080 
09-26 13:12:42.055 5782-14444/de.sebastian_brocks.camerasony I/System.out: [socket][/192.168.122.206:59573] connected
09-26 13:12:42.057 5782-14444/de.sebastian_brocks.camerasony I/System.out: [CDS]rx timeout:10000
09-26 13:12:42.088 5782-14444/de.sebastian_brocks.camerasony W/SimpleHttpClient: httpPost: Response Code Error: 500: http://192.168.122.1:8080/sony/system
09-26 13:12:42.090 5782-14444/de.sebastian_brocks.camerasony W/SimpleHttpClient: httpPost: IOException: Response Error:500
09-26 13:12:42.093 5782-14444/de.sebastian_brocks.camerasony I/System.out: [CDS]close[59573]
09-26 13:12:42.097 5782-14444/de.sebastian_brocks.camerasony I/System.out: close [socket][/0.0.0.0:59573]
09-26 13:12:42.099 5782-14444/de.sebastian_brocks.camerasony W/CameraServiceSony: openConnection : IOException: Response Error:500
```

Comment: `What could cause this?` there’s a million possible reasons I’m afraid. Do you have access to the camera’s error log? A 500 error should yield an error log entry with more info.

Comment: As additional information, if I just use calls to the camera API service, everything works. It's just the setCurrentTime call on the system API service that's causing the problems.

Comment: Hmm, the log doesn’t seem to have a lot more info :(  too bad. There’s no specific HTTP server error log that might contain more?

Comment: The http server my app is connecting to runs actually on the camera, there are no logfiles there.

Comment: Too bad. It might be worth trying to contact Sony’s tech support about this. Maybe you’re lucky and it’s passed on to someone knowledgeable

Comment: Upon further investigation, the error only appears on the 2nd or subsequent calls to setCurrentTime. When I turn the camera on and off between calls, it works fine. Weird.